# Implementing BlockChain on .HTML files?

Tags: blockchain, hyperledger

People are involved now a days with KYC implementation and Asset Management of BlockChain. I don't exactly know how they are taking the input in that case, but can we Implement BlockChain on .HTML files? 
Like taking particular input from User on a Webpage, and then doing the Base64 Encoding, and using it on a network of Blockchain?
I'm working on the Hyperledger project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can. That is the whole idea. You can indeed create a web based user interface to interact with your chaincode.
Have you looked at the demo examples available ? The [marble](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles/blob/master/tutorial_part1.md) one for instance ?

The backend of this application is the GoLang code running in blockchain network, while the Web based user interface is created to set the values and pass them to the chaincode. Interacting with the chaincode is done with a `HTTP REST` call to a peer on the network.

here is the marble application flow for you convenience,

[image]

Please visit [here](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/marbles/blob/master/tutorial_part1.md) for further details and guidelines.

Comment: In case your backend is Java based, a Java SDK is also available. See https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java